# what happens on heap space during spark shuffle stage

Tags: apache-spark

Based information from spark configuration page, I found that after switched to Netty from spark 1.5 Off-heap buffers are used to reduce gc during shuffle and cache block transfer. So, my question is that in today's spark, what happens in heap space during shuffle stage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general,Spark stores intermediate data on disk in case of shuffling operation for 'under-hood' optimization.This intermediate data will be reused within a same lineage(DAG) in case of re-computation of some part of the DAG.This can happen even if the RDD is not cached or explicitly persisted.

`spark.shuffle.file.buffer`

> Size of the in-memory buffer for each shuffle file output stream.
>   These buffers reduce the number of disk seeks and system calls made in
>   creating intermediate shuffle files.

[more config info](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#shuffle-behavior)

Before 2.x.x version

[image: For version 1.x.x]

Comment: Could you give more detail about the intermediate data about shuffling. And one more thing, can I consider that in current spark(2.1.0), what in heap will only be the intermediate data in computation job?

Comment: Spark 2.x.x is little different when it comes to where RDD/Dataset are stored.Intermediate data will be saved on disk irrespective of the version i suppose.Plus you got to understand about The Spark Memory structure. I just updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for kind response. One thing I hope to point out is that this pic is kind of out of date. After spark 1.6, the spark.shuffle.memoryFraction parameter will only be useful in legacy mode. They just introduce a new memory structure I think.

Comment: yeah. u are right. I forgot to mention the version. Just updated it. :)